# How do I use XPATH for taking a screenshot of a webpage element using Selenium for Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to automate taking screenshots from online Power BI reports using Python. I decided to use the By.XPATH method for finding the correct element, but I'm having some difficulties. Here's how the HTML for this part looks like;

```
<visual-container class="visual-container-component" _nghost-tue-c97=""><transform _ngcontent-tue-c97="" visualcontainerfielddraghover="" data-automation-type="visualContainer" data-testid="visual-container" _nghost-tue-c95="" drag-resize-disabled="true" preserve-aspect-ratio="true" class="bringToFront" style="height: 313px; width: 722px; transform: translate(14px, 59px); z-index: 6000;">
    <div _ngcontent-tue-c97="" ng-non-bindable="" skip-children-focus="" extended-shortcut-scope="" toolbar-anchor="" class="visualContainer unselectable readMode hideBorder visualHeaderAbove droppableElement ui-droppable" role="group" aria-roledescription="Lineplot" tab-order="2000" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" touch-action="auto" aria-label="Employment rate">
        <p _ngcontent-tue-c97="" role="tooltip" aria-hidden="true" localize="VisualContainer_VisualsEnterHint_OnView" class="visualsEnterHint" id="visualsEnterHint-5d5d9e204e6a18618e70">Hit Enter to inspect</p>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <p _ngcontent-tue-c97="" role="tooltip" aria-hidden="true" class="visualsEnterHint" id="visualsLabel-5d5d9e204e6a18618e70">"Unemployment in area"</p>
        <div _ngcontent-tue-c97="" class="visualContainerBorder themableBorderColor">
```

Now, the last line seems to be the correct line for me to call to capture a screenshot of the correct element.

I have tried using a full XPATH for this and found out that it is working, so in this case

```
/html/body/div[1]/report-embed/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/exploration-container/div/div/docking-container/div/div/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container[14]/transform/div/div[1]
```

However, the relative XPATH I made does not work when running the script.

```
time.sleep(5.0)
image_binary = drvr.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@aria-roledescription='Lineplot']/div[1]").screenshot_as_png
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_binary))
im.save(filename)
```

This gives me a `NoSuchElementException`, even though I am able to find the correct line from Chrome's dev tools when pasting my XPATH there. This also works when using the full XPATH for this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in language. When inspecting the HTML for the page, certain values were given in my native language, however when the web driver opened the page, these values were given in English instead. Changing this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `time.sleep(5.0)` try using selenium's waiting functionalities... like the `wait_for_element_to_be_clickable/visible` .

You can  set the max wait time to about 10-15 (or whatever you think it takes the element to appear).

This way you can be certain if it's appearing or not.

Tip: such long `XPATHs` can be confusing... maybe a typo crept in. Personally I prefer to use the `contains(text='')` functionality in selenium to find elements, although that may not be applicable in your case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using the waiting functionality as well, but that did not solve the issue, instead when testing with the full XPATH this gave me an empty screenshot instead, so I decided to go with `time.sleep` for now. As for the XPATH, I used the full XPATH only to test that the screenshot from this line works. I made a shorter, relative XPATH that does not work, which is exactly the issue I'm having here: `.//div[@aria-roledescription='Lineplot']/div[1]`

Comment: you can try storing the returned element as a python object and then call the screenshot function on it.
`elem = drvr.find_element(XPATH)` and then `elem.screenshot_as_png`.
Also, in python, you dont need to do all that imageBinary conversion anymore... just use `elem.screenshot('\\Path\\to\\filename')` .
As a last suggestion,maybe the element is not part of the visible screen?... try resizing the window using driver.set_window_size()